# flutter: How to use texture on Linux

Tags: flutter, dart, opengl, textures, native

I want to integrate OpenGL in Flutter project. I find [Texture widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Texture-class.html) seems to be the answer but all the examples I found is for Android or iOS. I saw [texture is supported in Linux engine](https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/24916) too. But I can't find any tutorial. Let's say I've create a triangle in native OpenGL C++ code. Flutter texture widget requires a texture ID. How can I bind this ID to OpenGL context so I can display this triangle in texture widget?